# Html Custom Checkbox And Label

Tags: html, css

Label comes top of checkbox. How to fix this ?

**HTML:**

```
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/>
<label  for="thing">Description</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background-image:url(uncheck.png);
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked +label {
    background-image: url(checked.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

[image: checked]

[image: unchecked]

Comment: Please add your CSS as well. This is not a problem with the HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/Vx6X4/

Comment: We need to see your CSS

Comment: ***How to fix this?*** your CSS knows how to start fixing it.

Comment: I think the problem will solve with margin-right:5px;

Comment: I know need css codes but doesnt add the post. I must add here sorry .

   input[type=checkbox] 
{
    display:none;
 }

  input[type=checkbox]  + label
   {
       background-image:url(uncheck.png) ;
       height: 20px;
       width: 20px;
       display:block;
       padding: 0 0 0 0px;

   }

   input[type=checkbox]:checked  +label
    {
         background-image: url(checked.png) ;
         background-repeat:no-repeat
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        display:block;
        padding: 0 0 0 0px;

    }

Comment: @cptc I've added it to your post for you.

Comment: Fixed with this.

label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 55px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}

Comment: You should give my answer a try though. It's easier to maintain, and like @KingKing said in the comments on your answer, the background-image solution comes with more complications than my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're using a background-image to do this. Background-images are placed behind the element itself, so that's why it appears behind it. To fix this, you could use the `::before` pseudo-element:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    height: 20px;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    content: url("uncheck.png");
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    content: url("checked.png");
}
```

That's the easiest way to add images to elements via CSS. Background-image was used back when not all browsers supported `::before`, but all browsers that support `:checked` also support `::before`.

Other things I've changed:

- I've placed quotes around strings (so the value of the attribute selector and the URLs)
- I've changed your `padding: 0 0 0 0px;` to simply `padding: 0;` since those have the exact same effect
- I've left out duplicate styles between `:checked` and the default styles. The `width`, `height` and `padding-right` will apply to the `:checked + label::before` just as well as the unchecked variant.

Answer (score 0):

I 've added this code block to css and problem fixed.

```
label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 55px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

Comment: no, it's not such easy, that kind of checkbox only supports 1 word for the label, otherwise each word will lie on a separate line. check this http://jsfiddle.net/V3Wcw/2/

Comment: to turn 1 word supported checkbox into 1 line supported checkbox, you can add style `white-space:nowrap` to the `label`, http://jsfiddle.net/V3Wcw/3/ However it supports only 1 line, it's of course totally usable in some cases.